# Удаление дубликатов из таблицы MSSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать запрос на удаление дубликатов строк из таблицы.  Нужно сначала выбрать из таблицы строки, с определенным значением по одному из столбцов. Затем проверить  найти среди них дубликаты по второму столбцу и удалить из них только те, у которых в  третьем столбце указано определенное значение. Спасибо.

Comment: Нужно сначала написать запрос на выборку строк с определенным значением по одному из столбцов, потом написать запрос для определения дубликатов и потом запрос на удаление строк с определенным значением.
Ну что за секретность то, а? Для чего прятать смысл задачи за неопределенными формулировками? Попробуйте со стороны прочитать свой вопрос и попробовать на него ответить - вы сможете понять, о чем речь идет вообще?

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример кода удаляющего дубликаты:

```
create table #MyTst (id int identity (1,1), num int)

insert 
    #MyTst 
values 
    (100),(100),(100),(100),
    (200),(200),(200),(200),(200),
    (300),(300),(300),(300),(300),
    (400),(400),(400),(400),(400),
    (500),(500)

--select * from #MyTst

;with MyCte (id,num,rn)
as
(
select id,num,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by num order by num) [rn] from #MyTst 
)

delete from MyCte where [rn]>1

select * from #MyTst

drop table #MyTst
```